# Crear un array con subindices mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una consulta de una tabla principal vinculada a una tabla secundaria pero con valores acumulables donde el registro primario de la tabla secundaria es el dni el cual sirve para vincular los datos personales asociados a cada dni. Pero cuando realizo la consulta inner join en la tabla secundaria me muestra los datos personales repetidos. Quisiera saber cómo mostrar todos los campos de la tabla secundaria pero sin que pueda repetir los datos personales de la tabla principal.

SELECT r.nivel, r.cedula,r.apellidos,r.nombres,n.lapso,n.castellano,n,matematicas from reg_estudiante as r

```
  INNER JOIN secciones s ON r.cedula=s.cedula 
  INNER JOIN notas_1 as n on r.cedula=n.cedula
  WHERE  r.nivel="1° Año" and s.seccion="A" 
  group by r.cedula
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ORDER BY r.nivel,s.seccion,r.cedula

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que agregues lo que lleves hecho (codigo y esquema de la bd) para ayudarte mejor con tu problema. Ya que de esta manera, carece de información.

Answer (score 0):

En MySql puedes agrupar y usar la función GROUP_CONCAT() o JSON_ARRAYAGG() para mostrar todos los valores de las columnas por las que no estás agrupando.

Tu foto muestra una estructura de tablas y tu query otra, así que no me quedó claro cual sería la query que estás probando.

Para la query que posteaste podrías hacer algo asíL

```
SELECT r.nivel, r.cedula, r.apellidos, r.nombres, JSON_ARRAYAGG(n.lapso), JSON_ARRAYAGG(n.castellano), JSON_ARRAYAGG(n.matematicas)

FROM reg_estudiante as r
INNER JOIN secciones s ON r.cedula = s.cedula 
INNER JOIN notas_1 as n on r.cedula = n.cedula
  
WHERE  r.nivel = "1° Año" and s.seccion="A" 
  
GROUP BY r.nivel, r.cedula, r.apellidos, r.nombres
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo también combinando `GROUP_CONCAT` con `CONCAT_WS` del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT_WS(
               ',', 
               r.dni, 
               r.apellidos, 
               r.nombres, 
               n.lapso, 
               n.castellano,
               n.matematicas
             )) AS notas
FROM reg_estudiante as r
  INNER JOIN secciones s ON r.cedula=s.cedula 
  INNER JOIN notas_1 as n on r.cedula=n.cedula
WHERE  r.nivel="1° Año" and s.seccion="A" 
GROUP BY r.cedula
```

Esta consulta te dará el resultado en una sola columna, con cada valor separado por comas, como indicas al final de tu pregunta.

Si quieres agrupar por columnas en cada tabla, puedes hacer algo así:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(r.dni, r.apellidos, r.nombres) AS alumno,
GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT_WS(
               ',', 
               n.lapso
              )) AS lapso, 
GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT_WS(
               ',', 
               n.castellano
              )) AS castellano, 
GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT_WS(
               n.matematicas
              )) AS matematicas
FROM reg_estudiante as r
  INNER JOIN secciones s ON r.cedula=s.cedula 
  INNER JOIN notas_1 as n on r.cedula=n.cedula
WHERE  r.nivel="1° Año" and s.seccion="A" 
GROUP BY r.cedula
```

Esta consulta te traerá en una columna la cédula, el nombre y el apellido y en otras columnas los valores de `lapso`, `castellano` y `matematicas` en sus respectivas columnas separados por coma.